# How to Call Tcl Scripts from PHP

Tags: php, scripting

Currently, I would like to call Tool Command Language Scripts that is located in server A.

When a user surf a website that is hosted in server B. When, a user click on a button for example, I would like the php file to execute the Tcl scripts that is located in server B.

How do I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [PHP execution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) (note that you should be **extremely** careful - if possible, limit to valid scripts instead of letting the user specify arbitrary commands in a GET or POST variable).

Example:

`http://myserver.com/php_scriptname.php?tcl_call=asdf.tcl`

```
<?php

if ( !file_exists("/path/to/tclsh") ) {
  die('unable to access TCL interpreter - check user permissions for UID ' . getmyuid() );
}

switch ( $_GET['tcl_call'] ) {

  case 'asdf.tcl':
    `/path/to/tclsh /path/to/asdf.tcl`
  break;

  default:
    die('invalid script called');
  break;

}

?>
```

**Edit:**

Your question presently reads:

> When a user surf a website that is
>   hosted in server B. When, a user click
>   on a button for example, I would like
>   the php file to execute the Tcl
>   scripts that is located in server B.

... but if you wanted to call a script on server "A", you could [set up an SSH key](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) and then call SSH from your script on server "B" - for example:

```
  case 'asdf.tcl':
    `ssh phpuser@servera '/servera/path/to/tclsh /servera/path/to/asdf.tcl'`
  break;
```

(Single quotes *and* backticks)

Note that you can store what is returned from the execution operator in a variable or echo it - you may want to echo the return value and include `2>&1` at the end of every command you run for debugging.

Comment: wow! that was pretty a good explaination. I will try this method and update you soon. Thanks again! :D

Comment: for ssh method, don't we need to specify the password in the script?

Comment: You should set up a limited user account for your script and use an SSH key - see link from answer: http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/